# Intraspecific variation in MCMCglmm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, lme4-nlme, glmm, ecology, phylogeny

I want to use `MCMCglmm` to account for phylogenetic autocorrelation on my GLMM. However I have more than one trait measurement for certain species.

Is there a way to account for intraspecific variation using `MCMCglmm` such as it can be done in geiger's `fitContinuous` including a vector of standard errors in `SE`?

Answer (score 1):

The `MCMCglmm` package is well suited to incorporating repeated measures of interspecific data. The following code demonstrates how to account for repeated measures by specifying a random effect for species in the `MCMCglmm` function. The `pedigree` argument did not work for me, so I use `ginverse` to specify the covariance structure of the random effect (i.e., the phylogenetic covariance structure).

```
# Load packages
library(phytools)
library(MCMCglmm)

# Generate data
phy <- pbtree(n=20)
dat <- fastBM(phy, nsim=12)
dat <- stack(data.frame(t(dat)))
colnames(dat) <- c("values", "species")

# Phylogenetic covariance structure of random effects
phy.inv <- inverseA(phy)$Ainv

# Fit model
fit <- MCMCglmm(values ~ 1, random=~species, data=dat, ginverse=list(species=phy.inv))
```